Math power function with modulo arithmetic in Python
I am learning group homomorphism (a Math concept) with modulo arithmetic. Basically, I want to show that g^(2x+8y) mod n equals to (g^(2x) . g^(8y)) mod n.
I have the following python code:
g = 57
n = 1000004119

import galois
GF = galois.GF(n)

# Adjusted values
x = GF(261099267)
y = GF(684728868)

# Direct calculation in field
lhs0 = pow(g, int(GF(2) * x + GF(8) * y), n)
print(f"lhs0 (direct calculation): {lhs0}")

# Separate exponent computations
exp1 = int(GF(2) * x)
exp2 = int(GF(8) * y)
print(f"exp1: {exp1}, exp2: {exp2}")

# Separate pow computations
lhs1l = pow(g, exp1, n)
lhs1r = pow(g, exp2, n)
lhs1 = (lhs1l * lhs1r) % n
print(f"lhs1l: {lhs1l}, lhs1r: {lhs1r}, lhs1: {lhs1}")

# Validate all expected relationships
assert lhs0 == lhs1, f"Final mismatch, lhs0: {lhs0}, lhs1: {lhs1}"

The last assert statement will fail with
Final mismatch, lhs0: 366446438, lhs1: 887364586

Why is that?

Fyi, if I change the x and y values above to:
x = GF(420)
y = GF(888)

the assert statement will pass. What is going on underneath in the Python code?
I expect there is no overflow error in Python. If there is, what precaution should I take in large integer modulo arithmetic in Python? Thanks.

python is not an arithmetic (or algebraic) engine. If you are doing special maths you should check relevant libraries and the limitation (which should be listed in the documentation). Bonus: they will be optimized. Also python and standard library has some limitations with a problem: such limitations and details are hidden in documentation.

Test it out in an algebra package or try Julia instead. I suspect you are running into some hidden maximum length of digits problem in the more brutal calculation. Strange that it doesn't give an error though. Can you find a smaller pair of numbers that elicit the fault?

I learned, with my friend's help, that g^(2x+8y) mod n doesn't necessarily equal to (g^(2x) . g^(8y)) mod n when 2x + 8y > n.
Basically x + y = z must hold in the integer field, not just modular arithmetic (Galois field), in order for g^(x+y) mod n = g^x . g^y mod n to hold.
If x = GF(261099267), y = GF(684728868), then
2x + 8y = 6,000,029,478, which is larger than n (1,000,004,119).
But in the case of x = GF(420), y = GF(888), then
2x + 8y = 7,944, which is smaller than n. In this case the homomorphism relation holds.
This is indeed a number theory problem, not python incapability of handling large integers.
